# Linux - Move files in multiple subfolders

Tags: linux

I've looked through other answers and they do not appear to quite fit what I'm trying to do, so please excuse me if I've missed something and this is a repeated question.

I'm trying to move files in subfolders. Here is the current folder tree:

```
Parent_folder
|     |SubfolderA
|     |     |Sub_subfolderAA
|     |     |     |FileAAA.abc
|     |     |     |FileAAB.abc
|     |     |     |FileAAB.abc
|     |     |Sub_subfolderAB
|     |     |     |FileABA.abc
|     |     |     |FileABB.abc
|     |     |     |FileABB.abc
|     |SubfolderB
|     |     |Sub_subfolderBA
|     |     |     |FileBAA.abc
|     |     |     |FileBAB.abc
|     |     |     |FileBAB.abc
|     |     |Sub_subfolderBB
|     |     |     |FileBBA.abc
|     |     |     |FileBBB.abc
|     |     |     |FileBBB.abc
```

What I would like to be able to do in this example is run a command which moved all files within the Sub_subfolders into their parent Subfolder, and repeats that for all of the Subfolders within the Parent folder.

Comment: Does the answer need to be a bash command?

Answer (score 1):

If there's nothing but files in your subfolders (no folders), these lines of code should do it:

```
cd Parent_folder
for folder in *   #loop over all folders in the Parent_folder
do
    cd $folder
    mv */* .      # move all the files inside folder to their parent subfolder
    cd ..         # go back to Parent_folder
done
```